# jar cannot find JSON file

Tags: java, json, jar

I built a jar out of my project. This project has a File folder containing different JSON files. 
[image]

I tried to read the JSON files like this:

```
public Status readStatus(){
    Status status = new Status();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        status = mapper.readValue(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/Files/Status.json"),
                Status.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;
}
```

When I run the jar file I get the following exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Status.json (The system cannot find the file specified)

I believe the problem is that I used the relative path to reference the files. I found different solutions in this forum explaining that I should use the method `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` so I changed the method to:

```
 public Status readStatus(){
    Status status = new Status();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        status = mapper.readValue(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Status.json"),
                Status.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return status;
}
```

After doing this I gat another Exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
>    at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 0]

How do I reference the file correctly so that it is found and read without throwing the InputException?

**EDIT: JSON file:**

```
{"changeTires":true}
```

**Mapping class:**

```
public class Status {

    public boolean changeTires = false;

    public boolean isChangeTires() {
        return changeTires;
    }

    public void setChangeTires(boolean changeTires) {
        this.changeTires = changeTires;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the resources folder instead of a folder in the root of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will simply wont work when you actually will distribute your app. If you want to serve files that will be shipped with your app, make those files a resource. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

In your case the most straightworward way would be to put `Files` in `src` directory.

Comment: thank you ! I didn't specify a resources folder befor building my jar...